# How can I add an object to a HashMap while I don't have a value for it

Tags: java, object, hashmap

I have an object `user` from a constructor `customer` and I want to add this object to the `HashMap`, but I don't have the values for `user` because it's input. After I added it to `HashMap` how can I check if this particular `user` is already in the `HashMap` or not?
`UsersList` is the name of the `HashMap`. 
 Here is my code:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Customer {


    int id;
    String Name;
    String email;
    String mobile;
    String password;
    String city;
    String postcode;
    public static String input;

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    Customer user = new Customer();

    Customer() {
    }


    Customer(int id, String Name, String city, String postcode, String email, String mobile, String password) {
        this.id = id;
        this.Name = Name;
        this.city = city;
        this.postcode = postcode;
        this.email = email;
        this.mobile = mobile;
        this.password = password;

    }


    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        System.out.println ("Enter your name:");
        String Name = scanner.nextLine();
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        System.out.println("Enter your email:");
        user.email = scanner.nextLine();
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getMobile() {
        return mobile;
    }

    public void setMobile(String mobile) {
        System.out.println("Enter your mobile number:");
        user.mobile = scanner.nextLine();
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        System.out.println("Enter your password:");
        user.password = scanner.nextLine();
        this.password = password;
    }


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getcity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setcity(String city) {
        System.out.println("Enter your city:");
        user.city = scanner.nextLine();
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getpostcode() {
        return postcode;
    }

    public void setpostcode(String postcode) {
        System.out.println("Enter postcode:");
        user.postcode = scanner.nextLine();
        this.postcode = postcode;
    }

    public void main(String[] args) {

        do {
            System.out.println("Enter \"login\", \"register\", or \"exit\"");
            input = scanner.nextLine();
            if (input.equals("login")) {
                // get login details
                user.setName(user.Name);
                user.setPassword(user.password);
                System.out.printf("%s login");

            } else if (input.equals("register")) {
                // get register details
                user.setName(user.Name);
                user.setMobile(user.mobile);
                user.setPassword(user.password);
                user.setEmail(user.email);
                user.setcity(user.city);
                user.setpostcode(user.postcode);
                HashMap<String, Customer> UsersList = new HashMap<>();
                UsersList.put("user", new Customer(id, Name, city, postcode, email, mobile, password));
                // Customer testCustomer = UsersList.get("user");
                // int id= testCustomer.getId();
                if (UsersList.containsValue(id)) {
                    System.out.printf("your account is already registered \n");
                }
                // String email= testCustomer.getEmail();
                else {
                    System.out.printf("you create your account succefully \n");
                    System.out.printf("Enter 'login' to log in or 'register' to open another account");
                    input = scanner.nextLine();
                }
            } else if (input.equals("exit")) {
                break; // exit the loop
            } else {
                System.out.printf("invalid input , try again");
                input = scanner.nextLine();
                // invalid input
            }
        } while (true);
    }
}
```

Comment: my teacher told me to not use database and instead of that hashmap , because its small project

Comment: You are instantiating a new HashMap inside your loop, each time you run it in an infinite loop. This alone causes all problems. Plus asking for user input from your own class definition is a really bad practice. A simple approach would be to construct a plain old java object with public getters and setters and a parameterized constructor for your fields. Ask for user input inside your main and then instantiate your class using the input.

Comment: See [Java POJO](https://www.javatpoint.com/pojo-in-java) for reference

Comment: i fixed what u said but i still idk how to check if particular user is already on Hash map or not , can u help me this is my update   if(UsersList.containsValue(user.tosting())){
           System.out.printf("your account is already registered \n"); 
        }
       
        else{
            UsersList.put(user,user.tosting());
        System.out.printf("you create your account succefully \n");}

Comment: This is not going to work this way. You dont even need a HashMap here. you can push the  ID to an array and then check if particular ID exists (your code needs a lot of correction). Better way to do this would be to use Serializable interface and store the data in a file so you dont have to rely on your code running all the time.

Comment: also, share a working code please

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you are looking for right now:

```
import java.util.*;

class Customer  {

      String  name, email, mobile, password, city, postcode;
    
    Customer(){}

    Customer (String name, String email, String mobile, String city, String  postcode, String password) 
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.city = city;
        this.postcode = postcode;
        this.email = email;
        this.mobile = mobile;
        this.password = password;
        
    }
    

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getMobile() {
        return mobile;
    }

    public void setMobile(String mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
       this.city = city;
    }
    
     public String getpostcode() {
        return postcode;
    }

    public void setpostcode(String postcode) {
        this.postcode = postcode;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.name + " " + this.email + " " + this.mobile + " " + this.city + " " + this.postcode;
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println(this.name + " " + this.email + " " + this.mobile + " " + this.city + " " + this.postcode);
    }
    
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        
    Customer user = new Customer();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<>();

    while (true) {
        System.out.println("\n\nChoose (1,2,3): \n1) Login \n2) Register \n3) Exit");
    
    int input = sc.nextInt();
    
    switch (input) {
        // get login details
        case 1:
            Scanner login = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.print("Enter name: ");
            user.setName(login.nextLine());

            System.out.print("Enter password: ");
            user.setPassword(login.nextLine());

            System.out.println("Logged with with => Name: " + user.getName() + "\n Password: " + user.getPassword());
            break;

        case 2:
            Scanner register = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.print("Enter name: ");
            user.setName(register.nextLine());

            System.out.print("Enter password: ");
            user.setPassword(register.nextLine());

            System.out.print("Enter mobile: ");
            user.setMobile(register.nextLine());

            System.out.print("Enter email: ");
            user.setEmail(register.nextLine());

            System.out.print("Enter city: ");
            user.setCity(register.nextLine());

            System.out.print("Enter post code: ");
            user.setpostcode(register.nextLine());

            if (!hm.containsValue(user.toString())) {
                hm.put(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), user.toString());
                System.out.println("Account created successfully");
            } else {
                System.out.println("User already exists");
            }

            break;
        case 3:
            //
            break;

        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong Choice");
    }
    }

 }

}
```